Estimate instantaneous rate of change
We are given a series of points that represent function $f(x): (0,2),(2,4.5),(4,7.25),(6,9.25),(8,11.29),(10,14)$
The question is to estimate instantaneous rate of change (derivative) of a function at x=8. There is no formula or graph given for the function.
At first I though I would calculate average rate of change from $x=6$ to $x=8$ and $x=8$ to $x=10$, so $\mathbb{arc}_1=1.02$ and $\mathbb{arc}_2=1.355$, then best estimate would be $\frac{\mathbb{arc}_1+\mathbb{arc}_2}2=1.1875$, but then I realized that is the same average rate of change from points $x=6$ to $x=10$ which makes sense.
Then I thought, the best we can do is say that instantaneous rate of change is a number within range $[1.02, 1.355]$, but instantaneous rate of change is supposed to be just one number? so I'm not sure that makes sense?
So, what is the best estimate? $1.1875$?
I'm confused about this because there are only points given.

Since, you are told to estimate there is no need to give a specific number so the range you found is, in principle,  a proper answer to the question.

The thing is, this isn't a smooth function. You have a collection of points, but to have an actual derivative you need to have a smooth + continuous function. Our function is isnt continous, so technically that's where the issue is.
TLDR; you dont have a derivative here since your function has jumps. lmk if you want a more detailed explanation!

It is implicit in the question that the given points are taken from a function defined over at least the interval $[1,10]$. The problem actually is that there are multiple ways to interpolate a continuous, differentiable function through a discrete set of points.

To calculate the instantaneous rate of change at point $x=8$ you must do the following steps. Calculate the average rate of change between $x=6$ and $x=8$, and then $x=8$ and $x=10$.
Here is an outline about how that calculation would look like:
\begin{align}
\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}&=\frac{11.29-9.25}{8-6}\\&=\frac{2.04}{2}\\&=1.02
\end{align}
This will be the lower bound of the estimate.
\begin{align}
\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}&=\frac{14-11.29}{10-8}\\&=\frac{2.71}{2}\\&=1.355
\end{align}
This will be the upper bound of the estimate.
The estimate bound will then be:
\begin{equation}
[1.02,1.355]
\end{equation}
To find the instantaneous rate of change you must then average those two values to get the rate.
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathbb{rate}_1+\mathbb{rate}_2}2&=\frac{1.355+1.02}{2}\\&=1.1875
\end{align}

This is bascially, "Yes, do it the way you did in the question." A reason would help this be an actual answer.
